# Getting phantomjs, socket.io and gevent-socketio to work together

Tags: websocket, socket.io, phantomjs, gevent-socketio

I am trying to build an application that utilizes Phantomjs 1.7 (simulating a browser) and create a Python back-end to fire up some events and collect data.

The problem is that the two processes Phantomjs and my Python program need to communicate bi-bidirectionally. The problem is that inside `page.evaluate` I cannot:

- pass any complex objects such as "fs" (to read from stdin)
- create a WebSocket to connect to my Python script
- any other form of inter-process communication is restricted

So my solution is simple:

- Inject socket.io js into the page I am viewing.
- Connect to my python server which is implemented using gevent-socketio

When I try to connect from inside page.evaluate I get:

```
Unexpected response code: 404
```

Here is the Phantomjs script:

```js
var page   = require("webpage").create();
page.onAlert = function(msg) { console.log("alert>>>" + msg); };
page.onConsoleMessage= function(msg) { console.log(msg); };

page.open("http://google.com", function() {
  page.injectJs("socket.io.js");
  page.evaluate(function() {
    var socket = new io.Socket();
    socket.connect('localhost:5051/test');
    socket.on('connect',function() {
      console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
    });
    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('signal',function(data) {
      console.log('Received a signal: ',data);
    });
    // Add a disconnect listener
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
      console.log('The client has disconnected!');
    });
    // Sends a message to the server via sockets
    socket.send("kakalq");
  });
    //phantom.exit();
});
```

And here is the server-side Python script:

```py
from socketio import socketio_manage
from socketio.server import SocketIOServer
from socketio.namespace import BaseNamespace

class MyNs(BaseNamespace):
  def initialize(self):
    print "connected"
    self.emit('connect')

  def disconnect(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print "diconnecting"
    super(MyNs, self).disconnect(*args, **kwargs)

 def signal(self, message):
   print "received signal", message
   self.emit("okay", "this will be sent to js")

 def start(environ, start_response):
   if environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith('/test'):
     return socketio_manage(environ, { '/test': MyNs })


if __name__ == "__main__":
  server = SocketIOServer( ('', 5051), start,policy_server=False )
  server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: dev, you could try to simplify your question, that makes it easier for others to understand your problem and identify the error. *page.injectJs("socket.io.js")* looks suspicious: Since it is a relative link it would reference `http://www.google.com/socket.io.js`. Try to reference it as `http://localhost/socket.io.js`.

Comment: @ren-dev did you find a solution? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866764/how-to-scrape-json-data-streamed-via-websockets-on-a-target-site

Answer (score 3):

My guess for why it does not work is that PhantomJS only supports the old, deprecated version of WebSockets. We have to wait a few months for PhantomJS 2.0 for it to support the current version of WebSockets.

Comment: for node.js socket.io server we can configure server to only listen through certain protocols-for example only through xhr polling-maybe this could help OP get around the issue with websockets, no? Does python socketio library provide that kind of configuration?