# Why don't I see a response from socket.io-client with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

```
var io = require('socket.io-client'),
    socket = io.connect('targeturl', {
        port: 8080
    });
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("socket connected"); //this is printed.
    });
socket.emit('list', {"user":'username',"token": 'mytoken'});
socket.on('message', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

socket.on('error', function(data){
    console.log(data); //nothing is printed
});
```

I see the message 'socket connected' when running this from node.js on the command line but I don't see a response from the 'list' call.

Note that this is a specific question about using [socket-io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) from Node.js as a command line application.

I have verified using `curl` that I can reach the socket server which is REMOTE i.e I do not have the server code but I know that it uses socket.io.

Comment: please add your server code too

Comment: The server is remote, I do not have the server code

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: some json output as a series of frames. I'm not sure if the socket.io-client takes care of the initial handshake and the docs don't help much.

Comment: Without providing (or having access to) any server code, it seems the issue is there

Comment: @JamieTaylor can curl to the server just fine so I'm not sure if that is the case to be honest.

Comment: @codecowboy I know this is old, but I run in the exact same issue. have you solve the problem back then?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on the matter, but it appears you're attempting to emit the message before the connection is established. (This stuff is asynchronous after all.)

Try moving the `emit` call inside of the handler for the 'connect' event, to ensure that it happens afterward.