# SocketIO + PhantomJS emit not working

Tags: javascript, socket.io, phantomjs, casperjs

I am having a pretty specific problem but I hope people can point me in the right direction for how to debug or even fix it. I am trying to write a local client which can run and test a webpage I had built which uses SocketIO.

I am running Phantom with the command line option --web-security=false since otherwise no in or out connections are legal as my local tester is not considered part of the same origin as my website I am testing (had to fix that before the listening would work).

Using PhantomJS I can't get the emit function from SocketIO to work. It just fails silently without any error. I know the socket is validly connected because it can listen to incoming events just fine (so the on() method works). I can run the same emitting code in a web browser and it works just fine.

Does anyone know alternatives to emit(), what lower level things emit() invokes that maybe I could patch, or how I should test things next? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15725236/1816580 There is a life sign for PhantomJS 2 on github.

Comment: Also found this now, came back here to share the link for fellow googlers :) https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research it looks like this form of sockets simply aren't yet supported in phantomjs.  When the new 2.0 releases they are supposed to be but until then other options are better.  I tried to find a shim for a while but was unsuccessful.

In the end, I instead used node.js to run the main script, make the socket connections and then used the phantomjs node module to do the browser interactions rather than running the script as a pure phantom script.  This meant that the api interaction logic got pushed to the node application and the phantom code was just about interacting with the page but I was able to achieve the testing goal this way so I count it as success.